# Print Item detail in ZPL zebra printer

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, receipt

I am working on recipt printing with Zebra printer.
I am able to print every thing but i would like to print
item detail from database for example i got dataReader
and would like to run loop to print all items on recipt .(c#)
So how i can run loop in ZPL programming.

```
^XA
^FX Name og adresse.
^CF0,60
^FO180,50^FDVitec AutoData AS.^FS
^CF0,40
^FO180,100^FDPostboks 545^FS
^FO180,135^FDSentrum^FS
^FO180,170^FDNO-0105 OSLO^FS
^FO50,210^GB700,1,3^FS

^FX Second Section.
^CFA,30
^FO50,240^FDName : ^FS
^FO450,240^FDDate :^FS

^FO50,280^FDcounter: ^FS
^FO450,280^FDTime :^FS

^FO50,340^GB700,1,3^FS
```

I want to run loop here on  DataReader that fetch data from database mysql,

```
^FX Third part  with barcode.
^CFA,30
^FO50,540^FDMVM's : ^FS
^FO450,540^FD0.00 ^FS

^FO50,580^FDSub Totalt: ^FS
^FO450,580^FD0.00 ^FS
^FO50,620^FDTotalt Amount: ^FS
^FO450,620^FD0.00 ^FS
^FO50,660^FDKontant: ^FS
^FO450,660^FD0.00 ^FS
^CFA,40
^FO50,700^FDBalance: ^FS
^FO450,700^FD0.00 ^FS


^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).
^BY5,2,150
^FO140,800^BC^FD122232^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can put a loop into ZPL code, it's a formatting language not a programming language.

You can, however, put the loop in your C# code and build strings that you can then concatenate.  Pseudo code:

```
string ZPL = "^XA ^FX Name...";
foreach( var item in dataReader) {
    ZPL += "^FO50,580^FDSub Total: ^FS" + item.SubTotal + "^FS";
}
ZPL += "^XZ";
```